# Building a tag cloud in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, tag-cloud

I'm trying to build a tag cloud in WPF based on [an existing implementation](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alanl/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18) [[Download Source](http://alanle.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/WPFTagCloud.zip)]. I didn't understand completely the implementation and my problem is, that instead of having the FontSize binded to the number of items in a collection, I want to bind it to some other values contained in a class. So in this part here,

```
FontSize="{Binding Path=ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}}"
```

I want to bind the FontSize to something else. How do I do that? Where does ItemCount belong to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemCount` belongs to the [**group**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx) inside the collection view that is generated from that Tag.

e.g. if i have a list

> A A B B B C

And i group them i get:

> Group A : ItemCount = 2
>   Group B : ItemCount = 3
>   Group C : ItemCount = 1

The whole point of a Tag-Cloud is to bind to that very property because you want to visualize how often a certain tag is used.

---

To respond to your comments, the bare-bones setup should be something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <vc:CountToFontSizeConverter x:Key="CountToFontSizeConverter"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2"
                       FontSize="{Binding Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I assume that your data-object class exposes the properties `Name` and `Count`, to make sure that the size changes as count goes up that data-object class needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), that is about all there is to it.

```
public class Tag : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = null;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _count = 0;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set
        {
            if (_count != value)
            {
                _count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I already have my data and I can't count them. What I have is more like a list of key-values of type string-int and I want to make a tag cloud showing the string with FontSize its int value.

Comment: Then you have absolutely zero use for that implementation. You can just throw that into an ItemsControl and template it. Well, you won't have to rewrite the converter at least, but all the grouping magic is pointless.

Comment: Maybe that's true. With your suggestion, will the tag cloud still be able to update dynamically as the list changes? Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Added some more info to my answer.

Comment: @H.B. Thank you very much. I'll work on that and come back if something goes wrong.

Comment: @H.B. I get an error on this line <vc:CountToFontSizeConverter x:Key="CountToFontSizeConverter"/>. Is there something wrong?

Comment: `vc` is a custom [`xmlns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) that i defined in my window, you can define the converter as in the implementation you used before. Incidentally the converter name is even the same but the converter i specified here is my own implementation which i wrote independently some time ago.

Comment: @H.B. I solved that problem and I managed to bind the Name attribute to the element. Actually I used a ListBox instead of a ItemsControl because I couldn't make that work as I wanted. Anyway my question is, how do I bind the Count attribute to the FontSize? The way I binded the Name is by manually setting SetBinding() of the ListBox to an ObservableCollection of class Tag. I try to do the same with Count but something goes wrong.

Comment: You not seem to know all that much about [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), do you? What you said does not really make sense. Why would one bind the Name by doing something with an ObservableCollection? You might want to check out [this article on data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) if you have trouble with the internal item bindings.

Comment: @H.B. No I do not. Maybe what I need to do is really simple but I don't know how to do it. I already read that article but I didn't understand a lot.. I guess the ObservableCollection is required because I want the tag cloud to be updated as new items are inserted in the collection.. Anyway though, without knowing what I did, it seems to work for now..

Answer (score 0):

ItemCount is a property of whatever instance is contained in the DataContext property of the WPF object you want to change the FontSize of. In the hierarchy tree, everything from `FrameworkElement` onwards inherits the "DataContext" property.

With ["snoop"](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) you can look into the UI tree of a WPF App at runtime and e.g. figure out what objects live in your DataContext at any given time.

Comment: I don't quite get what I'm looking for with snoop. Can't I just set the binding path to something else? For example a list of integers that I have in my main window?